# Ignore app/build in Android Studio 1.3+ in .gitignore

Tags: android, git

I want to add my whole Android Studio project to Git. Should I ignore the /build directory in app/build directory in the .gitignore file? From reading previous responses to a similar questions, I have seen that I should ignore /build.

My .gitignore file has the following lines:

```
.gradle
/local.properties
/.idea/workspace.xml
/.idea/libraries
.DS_Store
/build
```

Should I explicitly add app/build so as to ignore the build directory as I have another /build directory under the project directory?

Comment: i had `.gradle/
local.properties
.idea
.DS_Store
build
*.iml
`

Comment: https://www.gitignore.io/api/intellij,android